# Install of laravel/laravel failed

Tags: php, vagrant

I did vagrant ssh and into `vagrant@homestead`.when I installed `composer global require laravel/installer` and created `laravel new bacon` that caused bellow the error.

Also, I tried to set up `process-time-out` to my `composer.json` file  in order to solve the error that's not working.

Besides my `laravel installer version` is `4.1.1` on the vagrant@homestead

**here is the error**

```
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./bacon"
Installing laravel/laravel (v8.5.6)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v8.5.6): Extracting archive
    Install of laravel/laravel failed


  [RuntimeException]
  Could not delete /home/vagrant/code/bacon:
```

**Homestead.Haml**

```
folders:
    - map: C:\Users\taiga\github\project_laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: qcasts.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public
databases:
    - qcasts

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably composer 2.x, downgrading to composer 1.x should help:

```
sudo composer self-update --1
```